# Hierarchical Arc's in D3.js Sunbursts that include values at every level not just an aggegregate of the leaves

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

Hello Stackoverflow -

I have been attempting to create a sunburst chart using the examples provided at:
http://bl.ocks.org/kerryrodden/7090426 I can successfully replicate this particular piece of artwork - however, I have tried to add a twist and been unsuccessful thus far. Essentially these lines of code are what I believe I need to work with:

```
var partition = d3.layout.partition()
.sort(null)
.size([2 * Math.PI, radius * radius])
.value(function(d) { return d.size; });
```

I have tried a number of different variations on the line:

```
.value(function(d) { return d.size; });
```

including attempting to change the values of each parent to be set to a predefined value that I send over in the JSON. Essentially I want the chart to reflect how I have the JSON:

```
{
"name": "root",
"children": [
  {
    "name": "a",
    "size": 100,
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "b",
        "size": 50,
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "c",
            "size": 25
          },
          {
            "name": "d",
            "size": 15
          },
          {
            "name": "e",
            "size": 35,
            "children" : [
              {
                "name": "f",
                "size": 10
              },
              {
                "name": "g",
                "size": 5
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
      ]
  }
]
}
```

As you might notice each parent object contain the sum total of its children as well as its own value (set as size) the total value of the top most parent (root) is 100 because (a) is 100 however if you look at (b) which is 50 and (e) which is 35 there is 15 missing which is included in (a)'s size. I don't even know if what I want to do is possible or some variation. If you plugin in the json above the chart will render, but if you look at f and g they represent 100% of e when in fact what I want is for them to represent only 42% because the rest of e is represented by its own value plus f and g - thanks for reading have a great day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot comment because of low rep, so I'll have to give an answer. About the f and g representing 100% together: For all I know, that is normal behavior for d3.

I think you should prep your JSON data to reflect all the parts that you want to be shown (if that sentence makes any sense at all).

What i basically want to say is: if you want f and g to represent only 42%, you need an extra element h which has a value of 20. I don't think D3 has a way of figuring that out itself. Since it is data driven, D3 can only visualize existing data.

EDIT: 
After looking again, i would say that your data structure is not the way you would want it to be. I think you need something like this:

```
{
"name": "root",
"children": [
  {
    "name": "a",
    "size": 100,
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "b",
        "size": 75,
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "c",
            "size": 25
          },
          {
            "name": "d",
            "size": 15
          },
          {
            "name": "e",
            "size": 35,
            "children" : [
              {
                "name": "f",
                "size": 10
              },
              {
                "name": "g",
                "size": 5
              },
              {
                "name": "h",
                "size": 20
              }
            ]
          }

        ]
      },
      {
        "name":"i",
        "size":25
        }
      ]
  }
]
}
```

I have added element 'i' with value 25 so it completes element 'a' as following: a = b + i. You said that the value of the children ads up to be the value of the parent, but in the case of b, which seems to have 3 children, i came to the value 75 (25 + 15 + 35), so I changed the value of b and I added element 'i' with value 25 to get to the 100 of element a. D3 will pick up element 'i' and visualize it in the sunburst, just like element 'h'.

And like I said before the edit, I have also added element h, with value 20.

Comment: Hello Ocket-san: I should have clarified my question because it would be similar to e in the regard that I would want it to contain the child values as well as its "own value" in this case 25 - but as you pointed out with "e"  - you would need to fill the remaining 20 with another child value. I am wondering if my solution will have to allow the d3 to render its child elements and then tag all child element of that kind for removal after the chart renders (because in the example above I would not want i or h to be visible.) - it would be pretty hacky but I think it might work. thanks!

Comment: My pleasure. Just a thought on elements that should not be visible: perhaps those elements can have a special css class assigned, which makes them invisible (by setting opacity to 0 for example). That might be a bit less hacky :-)

Comment: So if I found a solution for my problem - any thoughts on how to get the answered posted? So it will show as answered?

Comment: :-) just post the answer yourself, include your code and if it really works, mark it as answered